# SAS dataset (for beginner)

Tags: sas

What means "outsurv" opiton in survival analysis?

Comment: Have you tried the SAS online help? It is generally very good.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing a survival analysis using product-limit method to test survival probability between two groups.

outsurv opiton will produce a dataset that contain survival estimates and confidence limits.

The OUTPUT statement tells SAS to write the current observation to a SAS             data set immediately, not at the end of the DATA step.  If no data set name is specified in the OUTPUT statement, the observation is written to the data set or data sets that are listed in the DATA statement.

see [here](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0194540.htm)

Comment: Dear Deep North,
Thank you for your clear and helpful explanation!!! :)